# Нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил функцию и х в этой функции заменялся на уже данное им значение

Tags: python, list

Вот что я уже пробовал, но х не заменяется

```
a = str(input("Введите начало отрезка   "))
b = float(input("Введите конец отрезка   "))

f = list(input("Введите функцию   "))

f = ''.join(f)

for i in range (0,len(f)):
    if i == 'x':
        i = a
print(f)
```

Comment: Что это за набор букв? Что это вообще такое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легко. Вот код:

```
f.replace('x', a)
```

```
a = str(input("Введите начало отрезка   "))
b = float(input("Введите конец отрезка   "))

f = list(input("Введите функцию   "))

f = ''.join(f).replace('x', a)
```

[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/)

Comment: @Lazie ;) Примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Вам похоже нужно что-то такое (чуть поправил код для наглядности):

```
def function(value):
    func_x = int(value) * 5
    print(f'Текущее значение х*5: {func_x}')


function(10)
x = input("Введите x: ")
function(x)
```

Вывод:

```
Текущее значение х*5: 50
Введите x: 20
Текущее значение х*5: 100
```